# slideToggle leaves empty space

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm busy on this project, which involves a banner to slide up and down on a button click:

```
 $("#open").click(function() {
    $("#banner").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

As you can see, whenever the `open` button is clicked, the banner slides up or down, depending on it's current state.

But when the banner slides up, there's an empty space being created as you can see on example 1:

[image: Example 1]

And when the banner is shown, there's very little space left, which is the effect I want to have, as you can see on example 2:

[image: Example 2]

(The 'parkbench' thing is the bottom of the banner, but if i'd screenshotted the full image the post would be way to long.)

Now, what I want to achieve is that the space between the two items stays the same, so also when the banner is not shown.

The HTML is pretty simple:

```
    <div id="banner">
            <div id="djbanner"></div>
        </div>



<div style="float:left; margin-left:0.55%; margin-top:210px; width:42%">
<div class="vak">
    <div class="vak_top"><p class="text">Box</p></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, 
</div>
```

I know that there's a div which isn't closed, but that's because there's another div under it, which isn't really neccecairy for the question.

Is there a way to achieve the effect I want to achieve?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Demo would be useful but this could be due to the margin-top you have there,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the following method:

```
 if ($('#banner').css("display") == "none") {
    $("#banner").slideDown(2100);
    $("#contentmain").animate({marginTop: '-329px'}, 1500);
 } else {
        $("#banner").slideUp(2100);
        $('#contentmain').animate({marginTop: '-480px'}, 1500);
    }
});
```

Stil, thanks for all answers tho!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the extra space is being caused by the layout of the div below it with the large margin-top setting. The quickest fix would be to change that margin-top in the same JS function with the slideToggle call, but ideally you'd want to eliminate the float and large margin-top and find a way to achieve that layout using regular page flow.